# PHP magic methods and order of operations

Tags: php, getter-setter

Given the following simplistic class...

```
class Test {
  public function __get($name) {
    echo 'Magic __get() called for: ' . $name;
  }
}
```

And the calling code...

```
$field = "Test";
$object = new Test();
$value = $object->$field[0];
```

So, first, I understand this example is super simplistic, but assume that I am expecting my "Test" property to be returned as an array, hence the last line `$object->$field[0]` being the first item of the Test property.

This is where I am seeing some very weird behavior. I have run this on at least 4 different computers, and seen two results... The results (in this simplistic example) have been:

```
Magic __get() called for: Test
```

OR

```
Magic __get() called for: T
```

It almost comes down to an order of operations type of thing. The array key [0] can be called BEFORE __get() is evaluated, resulting in `__get('T')` being called. Alternatively, __get() can be passed the full variable value "Test", and then the array key can be evaluated after. What is beyond confusing to me, is WHY I am seeing different results on different servers. I have seen mixed results with the same versions of PHP as well (7.0 and 5.6).

Does anyone have any ideas why the inconsistencies?

Comment: To be fair, your "Test" property isn't getting returned at all, it's getting echoed. On top of that, you are doing this weird variable interpolation type thing with `$object->$field`. I think this would be made a little more clear if instead you just did `$object->Test[0]`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect

Comment: Try writing it like this: `$object->{$field}[0]`. Also are the different computers running the same version of PHP?

Comment: @FatBoyXPC thanks, I know it's a little funky and am able to fix the issue, I guess I'm just curious as to why it's happening to begin with.

Comment: @Deadooshka thanks, I will look into that. None of the exact examples there match my issue, but there's enough hints there I am going to continue to look into them.

Comment: @Rob I will try this and report back. You know, I was seeing the behavior on both versions of PHP, but on my Mac, I am running 5.6, while the VM that serves my site is running PHP 7.0 (to match server). I wonder if while I was debugging, I was seeing the 5.6 behavior, and that would explain my issues. Going to look into this more.

Comment: Nevermind, @Deaddooshka. Example #2 from that table is literally what I'm running into. I'm still getting thrown off by a mac on PHPv5.6 running a VM with PHP7 serving the site, but behaving like 5.6. Odd. 
Thank you all for your help!